# Use FireBase database with android app only

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am considering using a FireBase database to store app data. What I would like to achieve is to have the data available to my app only.

Is this just a matter of creating a single account for my data and hard-coding the credentials into my app (similar to what I am doing now with my MySQL solution)? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Looking forward to your input.

EDIT: 
Let me just explain what I would like to do. I am developing a level based game. A players score is dependent on how fast he/she completes a level, compared to all other players. What I want is the following: I want to store the level data in a SQLite database on the device and to update this from a FireBase database. I do not want users to create an account. So, basically, I want my FireBase database to "act" more or less like my SQLite database: no login needed and only accessible to my app. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You could create an API Restful service using an MVC pattern with only one user and host everything freely on Heroku and MongoDB Atlas.
You could use as database MongodbAtlas, as server Nodejs Express and obliviously as a client your android app. It depends on your skills.

Comment: @Thecave3: Thanks for the info, but not really an answer to my question. As I said, currently I am using a MySQL database through an httpURLConnection. This works quite nicely, so the alternative should be a big step forward. I have the feeling FireBase is.

Comment: In general, your Firebase data is tied to your, and only your app so the question is unclear; what does *have the data available to my app only* mean. Are you expecting somebody else's app to access your data? Or are you asking how to secure your data so only your users can access it? Also, users that signup and authenticate with your Firebase are your, and only your users. Users of another developers app would not have access to your firebase. (*if you set your rules to read and write to true they would but that's an edge case)

Comment: @Jay: I have updated the question by explaining what I really want to achieve. Hope this makes things clear!

Comment: It's more clear but it's unclear is why you want to do this? If the data is stored in SQL on your device, why also store it in Firebase? Firebase is a real-time, live updating, cloud NoSQL database - how are you leveraging that? The question is just really to broad at this point. We'd like to help but it's a bit outside of what can be answered here on SO. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The reason I want to have it in the cloud is that part of the data is not static. If someone else has played a particular level, the target time is changing. So you need to update the data on you device. That is why I was looking at Firebase, to keep it synchronized. (PS: I will go through the guides. Hope my future questions are more to the point)

Comment: It really helps us understand your use case when the goals are clearly laid out. An example for future reference; *If someone else has played a particular level, the target time is changing*. If the level and data is stored locally, what specifically would need to be sync'd? Why don't you store all data in Firebase or... why not? Those of the kinds of details that make a question a good question. *How* are you using your database(s) and *why* are you wanting two databases (which would mean two code bases to support) etc. Going forward, include details to help us.. help you!